# Purchase existing domain and transfer to new registrar

Tags: godaddy, domain-registrar, domain-transfer

I am purchasing an existing domain from the owner who has it registered with GoDaddy.

I want to transfer the domain to another registrar and of course have it under my name.

If they update the registrant info to my name then it will lock down for 60 days. That's no good.

If they simply transfer it to my registrar, how will they update the registrant info?

I know about escrow services, but I don't feel I need one because I trust the seller and the amount is (relatively) small.

Advice? Thanks!

Comment: Did you really buy a domain owned by someone else? I have seen all these sites to buy/sell domains like sedo.com but I thought there is no market for such things. I've even seen hundrdes of domains on sale on ebay, but there is noone making offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initiate the transfer to the new registrar, and then change the administrative and billing contact info after the transfer goes through. If the domain is transferred to your account on the new registrar, then you can change the registration info yourself. This is typically how it's done.

Comment: I agree, I have done it this way in the past as well. Once the transfer goes through you'll be able to update the info from your account with the provider you are switching it to. I had no trouble at all doing this.

Comment: This is what I will do. Thanks guys. :) PS, congrats on hitting 10K!

Answer (score 0):

Open a godaddy account and have him transfer the domain to that account first (this is free, virtually instant and there is no lockdown period for internal transfers).

You can then update the information yourself and move the domain where you wish.